# I get compilation but 0 as my answer

Tags: c

Calculating e^x but I'm really new to programming.  I've made like two programs before. I've fixed any errors the shell points out yet get zero once it is run.

I have this :

```
#include <stdio.h>   

int main (void) {
    float answer = 1.0, x, next_term, n;
    int power;

    printf("Enter x: ");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("Enter the number of terms: ");
    scanf("%f", &n);

    next_term = x;
    for (power = 1; power <= n ; power = power + 1) {
        answer = answer * next_term;
        next_term = next_term * x / (power + 1);

    }
    printf("exp(%f) = %f\n", x, answer);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> exp(8.000000) = 0.000000

Comment: What are you entering for `n`?

Comment: What does your debugging tell you is happening?

Comment: I enter 50 or 100 and either doesn't give new value.

Comment: I don't know how to debug?

Comment: @Anotherreason Put a `printf` in the loop and print out `answer` and `next_term`. Then choose values for `x` and `n` that make it easy for you to compute the correct values by hand.

Comment: If you ask for 5 terms you should get an inkling of the problem.

Comment: I made n an integer and got value but now it is insanely high.

Comment: Don't you think you should learn to debug rather than just posting immediately on SO? I say that with your best interests at heart.

Comment: Yes. I just don't know where to start my professor isn't clear to me and programming is new.

Comment: Start by putting in more debugging print statements to trace the flow of your program and to see variable values at each point. Or better still, learn to use a debugger ([gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) is a common debugger to use if on  linux).

Comment: Thanks kaylum and everyone else. I'm not very good at this yet, but I'll learn. The program isn't bad, it will run once compiled, but my loop statement is wrong. It is supposed to calculate e^x, but while I know the resulting infinite series I don't code it right.

Comment: Why is `n` declared with type `float`? You seem to know enough to declare `power` as an integer. But why didn't you apply the same logic to `n`?

Comment: Figured it out. It's the answer * next_term in the loop. It needs summed not multiplied. Simple.

Comment: Drafting mostly. I know n isn't getting any values other than whole numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If you're calculating an infinite series, you want to *add* the terms, not multiply them... i.e. `answer=answer+next_term;`